# pythontex and xlop

Tags: pythontex, xlop

first of all, I am sorry if this has been already answered, I can't find any anwser !

When I try to compile this MWE :

```
% % % xelatex document.tex
% % % pythontex document.tex
% % % xelatex document.tex



\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{xlop}                       % Pour les calculs posés
\opset{decimalsepsymbol={,},carrystyle=\scriptsize\bfseries,
carrysub,lastcarry,offsetcarry=-0.4,
displayintermediary=all,displayshiftintermediary=all}




\usepackage{multicol, pgffor, multido}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[pyfuture=none, gobble=auto]{pythontex}



\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
import random
#
a=random.randint(50,1000)
b=random.randint(3,20)
q=a//b
r=a%b
def next():
   a=random.randint(50,1000)
   b=random.randint(3,20)
   q=a//b
   r=a%b
   return a,b,q,r
\end{pycode}

\pyc{a,b,q,r=next()}

$\dfrac{\py{a}}{\py{b}} = \textcolor{red}{\py{q}}+\dfrac{\textcolor{blue}{\py{r}}}{\py{b}}$

\opidiv[voperation=top, dividendbridge,resultstyle=\color{red}, remainderstyle=\color{blue}]{\py{a}}{\py{b}}


\label{LastPage}
\end{document}
```

I get errors :

```
Package PythonTeX Warning: Missing autoprint content on input line 59.

! Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again> 
                   \py 
l.61 ...mainderstyle=\color{blue}]{\py{a}}{\py{b}}
```

but if I comment out the line with \opidiv...., there is no problem.

How to make it run without errors ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A similar situation is described in the [pythontex manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pythontex/pythontex.pdf) in Section 8 *Troubleshooting* on page 57-59. There the example of `siunitx` is used, which needs to expand its arguments (i.e., inspect the final value returned by any macros inside of the argument), and `\py` is not expandable. For `\opidiv` the issue is the same as for `\SI` described in the manual.

The solution is also the same: construct the full macro call from Python, which means the values of the Python variables are inserted in the macro string in expanded form *before* xlop 'sees' them.

Here a version that uses the global `a` and `b` variables. Analogous to the manual example you can also construct a version that takes arguments from within the LaTeX code.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{xlop}                       % Pour les calculs posés
\opset{decimalsepsymbol={,},carrystyle=\scriptsize\bfseries,
carrysub,lastcarry,offsetcarry=-0.4,
displayintermediary=all,displayshiftintermediary=all}

\usepackage{multicol, pgffor, multido}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[pyfuture=none, gobble=auto]{pythontex}

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
import random
#
a=random.randint(50,1000)
b=random.randint(3,20)
q=a//b
r=a%b
def next():
   a=random.randint(50,1000)
   b=random.randint(3,20)
   q=a//b
   r=a%b
   return a,b,q,r

def xlopdif():
   return r'\opidiv[voperation=top, dividendbridge,resultstyle=\color{red}, remainderstyle=\color{blue}]{' + str(a) + '}{' + str(b) +'}'
\end{pycode}

\pyc{a,b,q,r=next()}

\section{dfrac version}
$\dfrac{\py{a}}{\py{b}} = \textcolor{red}{\py{q}}+\dfrac{\textcolor{blue}{\py{r}}}{\py{b}}$

\section{xlop version}
\py{xlopdif()}

\label{LastPage}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much +++

Comment: @silver In that case you should upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A less verbose alternative is to use `pys` command (or `pysub` environment).

```
% % % xelatex document.tex
% % % pythontex document.tex
% % % xelatex document.tex



\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{xlop}                       % Pour les calculs posés
\opset{decimalsepsymbol={,},carrystyle=\scriptsize\bfseries,
carrysub,lastcarry,offsetcarry=-0.4,
displayintermediary=all,displayshiftintermediary=all}




\usepackage{multicol, pgffor, multido}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[pyfuture=none, gobble=auto]{pythontex}



\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
import random
#
a=random.randint(50,1000)
b=random.randint(3,20)
q=a//b
r=a%b
def next():
   a=random.randint(50,1000)
   b=random.randint(3,20)
   q=a//b
   r=a%b
   return a,b,q,r
\end{pycode}

\pyc{a,b,q,r=next()}

$\dfrac{\py{a}}{\py{b}} = \textcolor{red}{\py{q}}+\dfrac{\textcolor{blue}{\py{r}}}{\py{b}}$

\pys{\opidiv[voperation=top, dividendbridge,resultstyle=\color{red}, remainderstyle=\color{blue}]{!{a}}{!{b}}}


\label{LastPage}
\end{document}
```